# RABL Sorting results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl, rails-api

Just started using RABL Gem w/ Rails 3.2.6 and getting my head around it. I am new to some parts of this stack as well so thank you for bearing with me.

I have a classroom model that has_many children through enrollments and I can output my JSON using RABL as such.

```
object @classroom
attributes :id, :name

child :enrollments => :children do |classroom|
    child :child do
        attributes :c_name
    end
end
```

Now I would like to actually order the children by some attribute (say c_name to keep it simple). How would I go about it? I tried having a helper method pick it up but did not get very far. Any ideas appreciated and welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try going in the child model and enter this:

```
default_scope :order => 'c_name ASC'
```

I think that should work. Of course, this will change the default ordering of the model.